# Qt menuBar() Error

Tags: qt4, menubar

I'm in the process of learning Qt4 and working through their tutorials.

In this tutorial:

http://doc.trolltech.com/4.5/mainwindows-menus-mainwindow-cpp.html

they have the following code:

```
fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
```

which causes the compiler to throw this error

```
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -I. -o MainWindow.o MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow.cpp: In member function ‘void MainWindow::createMenus()’:
MainWindow.cpp:56: error: ‘((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::menuBar’ cannot be used as a function
MainWindow.cpp:61: error: ‘((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::menuBar’ cannot be used as a function
make: *** [MainWindow.o] Error 1
```

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

[Edit] Added full error Message with g++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason QMainWindow was not getting setting up correctly. This was fixed by calling the base class constructor.

Comment: What do you mean "not getting setting up correctly"?  The base classes' constructors are always be called before the derived class's.  Sounds like you weren't declaring the inheritance properly, and now fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're inheriting from `QMainWindow`, you haven't created or inherited any fields which might shadow the name `menuBar`, and you've run `moc` (or had `qmake` do so for you)?

The `mainwindow.cpp`, `mainwindow.h`, `main.cpp`, and `menus.pro` from the example, unmodified, should work fine.

```
$ cd examples/mainwindows/menus/
$ ls
main.cpp  mainwindow.cpp  mainwindow.h  menus.pro
$ qmake
$ make
g++ -c -pipe -g -O2 -mtune=native -pipe -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o mainwindow.o mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -O2 -mtune=native -pipe -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o main.o main.cpp
/usr/bin/moc -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. mainwindow.h -o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -O2 -mtune=native -pipe -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -o moc_mainwindow.o moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -Wl,--as-needed -Wl,--hash-style=both -o menus mainwindow.o main.o moc_mainwindow.o    -L/usr/lib64/qt4 -lQtGui -L/usr/lib64 -L/usr/lib64/qt4 -L/usr/X11R6/lib64 -pthread -lpng -lfreetype -lgobject-2.0 -lSM -lICE -pthread -pthread -lXrender -lXrandr -lXinerama -lfontconfig -lXext -lX11 -lQtCore -lz -lm -pthread -lgthread-2.0 -lrt -lglib-2.0 -ldl -lpthread
$ ls -F
Makefile  main.o          mainwindow.h  menus*     moc_mainwindow.cpp
main.cpp  mainwindow.cpp  mainwindow.o  menus.pro  moc_mainwindow.o
```

Comment: I have qmake running it for me. 

qmake -project
qmake menus.pro
make

g++ -c -pipe -O2 -Wall -W -D_REENTRANT -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_SHARED -I/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/linux-g++ -I. -I/usr/include/qt4/QtCore -I/usr/include/qt4/QtGui -I/usr/include/qt4 -I. -I. -I. -o MainWindow.o MainWindow.cpp
MainWindow.cpp: In member function ‘void MainWindow::createMenus()’:
MainWindow.cpp:56: error: ‘((MainWindow*)this)->MainWindow::menuBar’ cannot be used as a function
.. [repeat for each Line] ..
make: *** [MainWindow.o] Error 1

Comment: I think ephemient is right Scott. That error message means the compiler thinks 'menuBar' is not a function, which almost certainly means you've got a variable, member or local, which is also called 'menuBar' and is blocking (shadowing) the function of the same name.