# Qt menuBar() not declared in this scope

Tags: qt, user-interface

I'm currently learning to program in Qt 5 and am doing an exercise in order to do so. I am currently having some trouble with a `menuBar()` that "is not declared in this scope", here is the problematic code block:

```
void MainWindow::createMenus()
{
    fileMenu = menuBar()->addMenu(tr("&File"));
    fileMenu -> addAction(newGameAct);
    fileMenu -> addSeparator();
    fileMenu -> addAction(exitAct);
}
```

I've check out a few other question and tried the solutions there but haven't had any success so far.
Apart from the official documentation I've also had a look at these other topics.

http://qt-project.org/forums/viewthread/23489
[Qt menuBar() Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1015202/qt-menubar-error)
[Adding drop down menu to Qt GUI - error 'menubar' no declared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8515327/adding-drop-down-menu-to-qt-gui-error-menubar-no-declared)

Comment: Your question is a bit generic. Did you try using accessing the object with `ui->menuBar()` instead of `menuBar()` directly?

Comment: I hadn't tried that, but it didn't seem to have any effect.

Comment: Can you show your `MainWindow` constructor?

Answer (score 0):

You can add menus and actions to the menubar like :

```
QMenu * menuFile = new QMenu("&File",menuBar());

QAction * newAction = new QAction("new", menuFile);
QAction * exitAction = new QAction("exit", menuFile);

menuFile->addActions(QList<QAction *>()<<newAction<<exitAction);
menuBar()->addAction(menuFile->menuAction());
```